# How would I go one directory back when I use __dirname in webpack

Tags: webpack

below is my code snippet:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        mode: process.env.DEBREL === 'Debug' ? 'development' : 'production',
        devtool: false,
        context: __dirname,
        entry: {
            sw: './xx.js'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'public', 'serviceworker'),
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', ".js", ".json"]
        }
    }
]
```

I understand that __dirname gives "/". so basically,

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'public', 'serviceworker'),
```

line will output "/dist/public/serviceworker"

I am looking for api/mechanism so that I can go one directory up and then "/dist/public/serviceworker".

is there any way I can achieve it?

**Example:**

if my webpackConfig.js file is at "C:\temp\project\mywebpack"
then __dirname gives "\" which is nothing but the mywebpack directory.
However, I want "C:\temp\project"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `let previous = path.resolve(__dirname + '/..')`. [Basic linux stuff](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+previous+directory)

Comment: unfortunately, It didnt work :(

Comment: __dirname gives the path to the folder that you are in. So if your folde project is called `my-project`, it will output: `/home/your-user/Desktop/my-project`.

Comment: what about `path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '../', dist....))`

Comment: isn't "__dirname" gives the path of the webpack.config.js?
If  "webpack.config.js" is in "C:\temp\project\mywebpack\" then __dirname will return "/"

Comment: @ PlayMa256  : thanks it worked :)